# Memory Issues in Akka/Spray application

Tags: scala, akka, spray

I have build spray service which would run in 2 8GB Boxes . It receives Json every 5 seconds which would get converted to MyJsonMessage .Each MyJsonMessage will contain 3000 MyObjects. So 3000 MyObjects would get created every 5 seconds.

Internally I am using batching to process these 3000 objects in batch of 1000s which will be sent to an consumerActor.

My heap size is set to 5GB.

I am emitting metrics. I have seen YGC time increasing at a very high rate , even heap size grows and frequently touches 5 GB.  I am new to Akka so I am not sure if there is any memory leak here or only option is to add more boxes. Solutions/Suggestions?

```
case class MyJsonMessage
(
  inputString1:String,
  inputString2:String,
  objectList:List[MyObject]
)

case class MyObject
(
  objectName : String,
  objectValue : String,
  data : Map[String,String]
)


class MyHttpService (implicit val context: akka.actor.ActorRefFactory        
.....) extends MyJsonProtocol
{

 def worker = MyHttpServiceWorker
 val multicastRoute = path("service" / "task" / segment) { 
 (configName: String) => {
 post { ctx =>
  var payload = try {         
 Left(JsonParser(ctx.request.entity.asString).convertTo[MyJsonMessage])
     } catch {
      case ex: Exception =>
         log.error("Error converting message payload: ", ex)
         Right(ex)
     }     
     worker.process(payload.left.get)
 }

object MyHttpServiceWorker
{
    def process[T](request: T) = {
   request match {

    case request : MyJsonMessage =>
       val objectListCount = request.objectList.size
       val batches = objectListCount > 1000 match {
        case true => ceil(objectListCount * 1.0 / 1000).toInt
        case false => 1
      }

    List.range[Long](0, batches).foreach(batch => { 
       val split = MyBulkObjectRequest(request, batch.toInt * 
        batchSize, limit * batchSize)
        MyObjectRequestConsumer ! split
        limit += 1
      })

  MyObjectSuccessResponse(objectListCount, batches, requestId , UUID))     

   }
}
```

Following is the dispatcher for MyObjectRequestConsumer in conf

```
myobject-dispatcher {
    type = Dispatcher
    executor = "fork-join-executor"
    fork-join-executor {
       parallelism-min = 16
       parallelism-factor = 4.0
      parallelism-max = 16
     }
   throughput = 1
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the CPU utilization high? If not, you can consider to create more `MyObjectRequestConsumer` to handle the messages.

From you example I assume you only create one `MyObjectRequestConsumer` (It doesn't look like a Router). That means all the message `split` are queued in the mailbox of `MyObjectRequestConsumer` and processed one by one.

You can simply create a router to see if it helps

```
val router: ActorRef =  context.actorOf(RoundRobinPool(5).props(Props[MyObjectRequestConsumer]), "router")
router ! split
```

More information about [AKKA Routing](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/routing.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes I am creating the Routing pool in my main class as follows      -                                                                                                                          system.actorOf(ClusterRouterPool(AdaptiveLoadBalancingPool(
SystemLoadAverageMetricsSelector), ClusterRouterPoolSettings(
totalInstances = instances , maxInstancesPerNode = instances, allowLocalRoutees = isLocal, useRole = None) ).props(Props[T]).withDispatcher(dispatcher), name)